# Scroll to bottom of div when close to bottom

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar, chat

I am working on a chatting service and i need the site to scroll to the bottom of the chatt, and if a person whants to scroll up, the script for scrolling down will stop.
I have the chat inside a div with the id #chat_innhold, and here is my attemnt.

```
window.setInterval(function scrolled(o)
{
        if(o.offsetHeight + o.scrollTop > o.scrollHeight - 75)
        {
            window.setInterval=function()
                {
                return false;
                }
        }
        else
        {
            window.setInterval=function()
                {
                $("html, #chat_innhold").animate({ scrollTop: $('#chat_innhold').prop("scrollHeight")}, 'slow');
                }
        }
}, 1000);
```

When i am 75 pixels above bottom, a want to stop the scroll to bottom function.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you overriding window.setInterval?

Comment: its just bad coding...Im very new to javascript, and i see the mistake. i think its supposed to be two different functions or something like that

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need something like that

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Go to bottom</button>
  <button class="go-top">Go to top</button>
</div>

body,
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
}
.go-top {
     bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

var elem = $('.wrapper')[0];
if (elem.addEventListener) {
  if ('onWheel' in document) {
    // IE9+, FF17+, Ch31+
    elem.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
  } else if ('onmousewheel' in document) {
    // old variant
    elem.addEventListener("mousewheel", onWheel);
  } else {
    // Firefox < 17
    elem.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", onWheel);
  }
} else { // IE8-
  elem.attachEvent("onmousewheel", onWheel);
}

function onWheel(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;
    if(delta < 0 || delta > 0) {
        $('html, body').stop();
  }
}

var deltaWindowBodyHeight = $('body').height() - $(window).height();

function goToBottom() {
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: deltaWindowBodyHeight - 75
    }, 1000);
}
function goToTop() {
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000);
}
$('button').click(function() {
if($(this).hasClass('go-top')) {
    goToTop();
} else {
    goToBottom();
}
});
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/3b1d6bgg/1/)

Comment: what i ment was that the scrollbar will always be at the bottom, unless a user starts to scroll upwards.
Since its a chatting service i want all new chats to show up on the bottom when new info shows up, and if the user scrolls up, the function will stopp the always on the bottom script. Hope it makes sence :)

Comment: Here is the script that i got working, but i want to stop the function, when i am using the scrollwheel:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 window.setInterval(function() {
  $("html, #chat_innhold").animate({ scrollTop: $('#chat_innhold').prop("scrollHeight")}, 'slow');
  }, 1000);
</script>

Comment: @Rein Bentdal what is your argument 'scrollHeight'?

Comment: Im using scrollHeight, to get to the bottom of the div. Its a scrollable div.

Comment: @Rein Bentdal, in general case you should use "clearInterval" to stop interval function, for this you have to name your interval function like this:
var myIntervalFunction = window.setInterval(function() { $("html, #chat_innhold").animate({ scrollTop: $('#chat_innhold').prop("scrollHeight")}, 'slow'); }, 1000);

And now you can use name of your function when it is necessary

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I will try to use your script, and see how it behaves in my inviorment!